# Is it possible to execute a function using eval?

Tags: javascript, eval

I have a scenario, where I accept huge functions script in the string and need to execute it in real time. A simple example of it is as follows...

```
var fn = "function(){}";
eval(fn);
```

However, I am getting an error for the above script. Is there a way that I can do this or is it totally discouraged?

Comment: It’s possible to make that work (by adding parentheses), but `eval` is almost never necessary. What are you using it for exactly?

Comment: `var fn = "(function() { return 42; })();";
alert(eval(fn));`

Comment: Hi Ryan. I am working on a project where some simple code snippets will be defined inside mongo database which will be executed on nodejs while serving an API request. So the functionality will keep varying based on different models dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

```
var fn = "function(){}";
eval("(" + fn + "())");
```

Or, if you want to define the function so it can be called later:

```
var fn = "function(){}";
eval("fn = " + fn);
fn();
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Your first model works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Are you simply looking for a function constructor from string, then you can do this without eval.

```js
// Using eval
eval("var evalfn=function(){console.log('in evalfn'); return 11}");
var ret1 = evalfn();
console.log("eval ret1:" + ret1);

// Using new Function() without arguments
var fn = new Function("console.log('in fn'); return 12");
var ret2 = fn();

console.log("fn ret2:" + ret2);

// Using new Function() with arguments
var fnwithargs = new Function("a", "b", "console.log('in fnwithargs'); return a+b");
var ret3 = fnwithargs(10, 5);

console.log("fnwithargs ret3:" + ret3);
```

Notice that with this technique, your strings cannot contain the keyword function(). Instead you provide variable names and the function body to the Function constructor.

Comment: You don't need curlies around the body, `new Function("console.log('in function'); return 12")` does the same thing. It should also be strongly noted that all disclaimers and caveats for `eval` also apply to `new Function`.

Comment: Right you are, Amadan.

Comment: @Amadan: Not all of them. Direct `eval` runs in the current scope, which, if dynamic code is almost never necessary, is extra-almost-never-necessary.

Comment: @Ryan: You're right, not _all_ of them.

Comment: Thank you for your response. But my requirement desires something like below var fn = "function(){}";
eval("(" + fn + "());");

Comment: Well, I think that is close to what @Michael Saunders is suggesting in his answer, then.